# How to work with readPixel and writePixel in JuicyPixels, Haskell?

Tags: image, haskell, image-processing, pixel

In [this](https://www.stackbuilders.com/tutorials/haskell/image-processing/) article I've found some examples of using `MutableImage` with `readPixel` and `writePixel` functions, but I think it's too complicated, I mean, can I do that without `ST Monad`?

Let's say I have this

```
eDynamicImage <- readImage
eImage <- convertRGBA8 <$> eDynamicImage
```

so I can apply `pixelMap` based filters to that image like this `negative <$> eImage`, but how do I work with pixels and it's coordinates? Can someone explain me what is `Mutable Image` and how can I get this from `DynamicImage` or `Image`?

Is there any clean code that can rotate image using this function?

UPD 2.0: I've made totally working rotation function using built-in JuicyPixels `generateImage` function:

```
rotate :: Double -> Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8
rotate n img@Image {..} = generateImage rotater newW newH
  where rotater x y = if srcX x y < imageWidth && srcX x y >= 0 && srcY x y < imageHeight && srcY x y >= 0
                       then pixelAt img (srcX x y) (srcY x y)
                       else PixelRGBA8 255 255 255 255
        srcX x y = getX center + rounding (fromIntegral (x - getX newCenter) * cos' + fromIntegral (y - getY newCenter) * sin')
        srcY x y = getY center + rounding (fromIntegral (y - getY newCenter) * cos' - fromIntegral (x - getX newCenter) * sin')
        center = (imageWidth `div` 2, imageHeight `div` 2)
        newCenter = (newW `div` 2, newH `div` 2)
        newW = rounding $ abs (fromIntegral imageHeight * sin') + abs (fromIntegral imageWidth * cos')
        newH = rounding $ abs (fromIntegral imageHeight * cos') + abs (fromIntegral imageWidth * sin')
        sin' = sin $ toRad n
        cos' = cos $ toRad n
```

where

```
rounding a = floor (a + 0.5)
getX = fst 
getY = snd
toRad deg = deg * (pi/180)
```

That's it if someone need it. Thanks @Carsten for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `MutableImage` is one you can *mutate* (change in place) - `Image`s are immutable by default. You'll need some kind of monad that allows that though (see the documentation - there are a few including `ST` and `IO`).

To get an `MutableImage` you can use [`thawImage`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#v:thawImage) - then you can work (get/set) pixels with [`readPixel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#v:readPixel) and [`writePixel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#v:writePixel) - after you can [`freezeImage`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#v:freezeImage) again to get back an immutable `Image`

If you want to know how you can rotate images you can check the [`source code`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-extra-0.4.1/docs/src/Codec.Picture.Extra.html#rotateLeft90) of [`rotateLeft`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-extra-0.4.1/docs/Codec-Picture-Extra.html#v:rotateLeft90) :

```hs
rotateLeft90 :: Pixel a => Image a -> Image a
rotateLeft90 img@Image {..} =
  generateImage gen imageHeight imageWidth
  where
    gen x y = pixelAt img (imageWidth - 1 - y) x
```

as you can see it does not use a *mutable image* but generates a new one from the olds pixels (using [`pixelAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture.html#v:pixelAt) instead of `readPixel`)

just in case - this is using the [record-wildcards](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/record_wildcards.html) extension to extract all the fields from the `Image a` - parameter (that is what the `Image {..}` does - `imageHeight`,`imageWidth` is pulled from there)

Comment: Could you, please give an example of rotating on non arbitrary angle (image orientation may be not switched, like, white background instead of empty pixels)? I've tried to rewrite using sample from article I've mentioned, but there's error while executing `.\\Data\\Vector\\Generic.hs:248 ((!)): index out of bounds (2668000,2668000)` . I was trying to use this formulas `let coordX = rounding $ (cos (toRad n) * fromIntegral x) - (sin (toRad n) * fromIntegral y)` and `let coordY = rounding $ (sin (toRad n) * fromIntegral x) + (cos (toRad n) * fromIntegral y)`. `rounding` is just `Double -> Int`.

Comment: And also I've tried following: `let newX | coordX >= imageWidth || coordX <= imageWidth = 0
                         | otherwise = coordX` and 
                `let newY | coordY >= imageHeight || coordY <= imageHeight = 0
                         | otherwise = coordY `

Comment: you mean rotating using an arbitrary angle? It's a bit hard to tell without seeing all of your code but if I read this right you are rotating around the origin so you'll produce "negative" coordinates ... the second comment is a bit strange too as of course every number is either >= or <= coordX so you only produce 0

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean arbitrary. I was putting those `newX` and `newY` into `writePixel` function, changing nothing else in example...

Comment: yeah but if I get your code right `newX = 0` and `newY = 0` always - you only change one pixel - also you should have a look about how to calculate rotated coordinates - your formula seems to be around origin - which is fine - I think you want the center though - in that case first translate with (-width/2,-height/2), rotate with your formula and then translate back (width/2,height/2) - also crop out of range pixels (coords < 0 | > =width/height) - but IMO this is another question unrelated to the original one here

Comment: PS: not a good idea to rotate the pixels in place anyway - you'll overwrite coordinates you later want to rotate so you lose parts of the image and "copy" over others - better go with the version used in `rotateLeft90` where you create a new one

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, your example helped a lot!